# BackboneJS fails to go to .fail when api call times out

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I'm new to backbone. I found the code that adds the Deferred so we can add promise. This is the code

```
getPatientInfo: function fetch(options) {
   var deferred = $.Deferred();
   Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.call(this, _.extend({ 
     deferred: deferred
     }, 
     options));
   return deferred;
 },
```

And the code that calls getItem function is this

```
  this.item.getPatientInfo().done(_.bind(function() {
    this.renderPatient(this.item);
  },this))
  .fail(function(error){
    // This won't show unlike native $.ajax .fail where it will show the error
    // Not sure why it's not working
    console.log(error);
  });
```

However, when I try to simulate a failure like turning off my network, the .fail won't catch the failed GET request. I won't execute console.log(error);

But if I change it using native jquery like using $.ajax().success().error(function(error){console.log(error)}), the .error will work and I'll be able to see the error in my console tab.

What is wrong?

UPDATE to prevent issues but not ideal I think. Patching it because it's missing is not a good idea

```
  this.item.getPatientInfo().done(_.bind(function() {
    if (this.item.attributes.info !== undefined) {
      this.renderPatient(this.item);
    }
  },this))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone Model already returns a deferred, I see no good reason for this overcomplicated implementation - it's a better to work with Backbone than against it. e.g.

```
var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
});

var someModel = new SomeModel();
someModel.fetch()
.done(function(response) {
    console.log('Post title: ', response.title);
    console.log('Post body: ', response.body);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('failed');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/5zzzchpq/

Note you can also access the new attributes in `done` i.e. `someModel.get('title')`, or instead of those deferred callbacks you can use the `'sync'` and `'error'` events the model triggers for success and failure.

Comment: since I'm calling fetch like this, this.item.getPatientInfo() which is a function, how will I change it to use Backbone's fetch?

Comment: good news, this.item.fetch() is working and I do get the response from our api. What's wrong though with the Deferred code above?

Comment: After removing our prototype, the .fail() is now working. However, I'm curious why the code above is making it fail.

Comment: Dominic Tobias, I looked at backbone.js file, I didn't see any mention of done and fail. Are you sure it's from BackboneJS?

Comment: @devwannabe If you have a look about 3/4 down the Backbone source @ "Backbone.sync" this returns the result of Backbone.ajax, which is `Backbone.ajax = function() { return Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, arguments);  };` -- so basically the result of `$.ajax` - are you still having problems?

Comment: would that mean that the result being returned to Backbone is also deferred?

Comment: `fetch` calls `sync`, which calls `$.ajax` - so it returns the same `$.Deferred` object that jQuery does yep

Comment: I'm still seeing issues but it's way better than using our own protype.fetch. Maybe I shouldn't use .done. I noticed the object that we are using which is this.item has incomplete attributes. Any ideas about that? It only happens when I try to simulate network failure. That means, when it goes executes the code inside .done(), it will fail because this.item.attributes has a missing property that I need. I don't want to use -> if (this.item.attributes.info !== undefined) { .... }

Comment: I updated the main post. I included the IF statement which I mentioned on my last comment

Comment: It's all good! I see the ajax method in jquery being called after this code gets called - return Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, arguments);